# How to get the format YYYY-MM-DD from getLocaleDateFormat in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have the following line of code:

```
getLocaleDateFormat('en-CA', FormatWidth.Long )
```

I want to get `YYYY-MM-DD`. I am getting `MMMM d, y`.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

From Angular 6 you can use following:

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
formatDate(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'en');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import frenchCanadianLocaleData from "@angular/common/locales/fr-CA";
```

Look at the return array and the 11th value in the array.

```
['y-MM-dd', 'd MMM y', 'd MMMM y', 'EEEE d MMMM y']
```

Looks like short (1st value) is correct-enough, but the rest aren't. 'y-MM-dd' shows something like 2022-12-08, which might be what you're looking for.

Time is the 12th value in the array, and it appears to be correct:

```
["HH 'h' mm", "HH 'h' mm 'min' ss 's'", "HH 'h' mm 'min' ss 's' z", "HH 'h' mm 'min' ss 's' zzzz"]
```

We needed the correct locale-specific format for date and time with seconds.

Here's what worked for us:
we hard-coded the date to short, the time to medium, and just put a space between them. We ignored the data in getLocaleDateTimeFormat (13th value in the array) because what it returns wasn't helpful for us.

```
    const locale = 'fr-CA';
    const dateFormat = getLocaleDateFormat( locale, FormatWidth.Short );
    const timeFormat = getLocaleTimeFormat( locale, FormatWidth.Medium );
    this.dateTimeFormat = dateFormat + ' ' + timeFormat;
```